# Is it possible to take a picture from the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, flash

I need to save an image from the clipboard, how?

Zero Clipboard - does not know how to do it

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807951/paste-clipboard-image-to-canvas it seems relavent. no?